# How to find the kernel source corresponding to the Ubuntu of specific version?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

Recently, I'm doing some research about wireless network, in order to achieve my experiment goals, some changes must be done about mac80211_hwsim, but it's fail to find the kernel source corresponding to the Ubuntu of specific version? It's helpful a lot if someone can tell me how to solve this problem. Thanks!

`lihui@ubuntu:~$ modinfo mac80211_hwsim
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Software simulator of 802.11 radio(s) for mac80211
author:         Jouni Malinen
srcversion:     FEC587C589C9B337D559437
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           radios:Number of simulated radios (int)
parm:           channels:Number of concurrent channels (int)
parm:           paged_rx:Use paged SKBs for RX instead of linear ones (bool)
parm:           rctbl:Handle rate control table (bool)
parm:           support_p2p_device:Support P2P-Device interface type (bool)
parm:           regtest:The type of regulatory test we want to run (int)
lihui@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command below to get the source of current system kernel：

```
sudo apt-get source linux-source
```

[There is a good reference with more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code).

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have found a correlation solution at [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), which seems to be similar to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make changes to the mac80211_hwsim kernel module?
If so you will have to download the code for Linux 3.16, you will find the code at linux/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.c.

You can easily find material about downloading and setting up the kernel environment online.

If you want to learn and use the kernel module the below link is pretty good.
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/mac80211_hwsim

Comment: I have already read this web page, from which I got to know how to use mac80211_hwsim module, but it contributes a little on modifying some behavior of mac80211_hwsim module, I wonder if it's possible for you to provide me more information about making changes to mac80211_hwsim module. Your kind help is highly appreciated!

Comment: @HuberyLee: Do you need to modify the module recompile it and run? Or do you want to just learn the details on how to use the module?

Comment: Oh.. ignore the above comment. Just read your comment on the other answer. :)